# IPv4 checksum contradicting wireshark

Tags: wireshark, checksum, pcap

I'm sending some udp packets over ethernet. I use BuilUDPPacket method in pcapdotnet to build packets.  This method calculates checksum on its own. After I capture the sent packets by wireshark it shows some other value of checksum than what my prgram is using. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you have any hardware that is doing checksum calculations which could affect calculations done by the software?

Comment: Yes.hardware is apparently doing checksum calculation to reduce driver software offload,looks like wireshark is capturing the checksum calculated by h/w & not that which is calculated by by program.Makes sense. Thanks